# How can I load an Android raw dd image into Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, computer-forensics

I would like to use in the Android emulator de same environment, apps, data, etc. from an Android phone. I have already done dd images of cache, data and system.

How I can load in the Android emulator this images?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK Emulator has individual dd/img images for system, userdata, cache, etc.  The userdata volume is the one you are most interested in, so you could try to swap that out for your own.  The tougher issue will be with the file system.  I think that the kitkat build in the emulator is finally using EXT4 file system, but the earlier versions all use YAFFS2.  The YAFFS2 that is used on the older model phones is often a different version than the emulator uses, just to make things even more difficult.

In short, I don't think you will be able to do this.